# Dialog shows only the second time a button is pressed to activate it

Tags: android, dialog, show-hide, timepicker, android-datepicker

I have some problem with `TimePickerDialog` and `DatePickerDialog`,
Code as following:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.equals(checkInTime)) {
        showDialog(1);
    }

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    if (id == 1) {
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, this, dt.getHourOfDay(), dt.getMinuteOfHour(), true);
    }

    return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}
```

It works like a charm until I press "Set" in the dialog, then next time I click on the button nothing happens (the dialog doesn't appear), but if I click one more time the dialog shows again. It shows every time until I press "Set" then it won't work for one click, but start working again on the next click.

The same problem happens with DatePickerDialog. Does anyone have any ideas?

The listener is not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `dismiss()` in your dialog (`TimePickerDialog`) is the problem. It is the same as calling `cancel()`, `onBackPress()`, because it calls `dismiss()`. Instead you can call `hide()`.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar problem.
On emulator all was ok, but on Samsung Galaxy Note [android 4] showing DialogDatePicker every second time failed. I suspect sth is wrong in hidding/dismissing DialogDatePicker.

All started working fine after adding listener for 'ok' button.

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, callBack, fakeYear, fakeMonth, fakeDay);
dpd.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, getString(android.R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
         System.out.println("here nothing more is needed");
         System.out.println("dialog closed and next time appear again");
      }
   }
});
```